# Javascript greatest sum of triple digits

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I want to write a function, in javascript, that calculates the greatest sum of 3 consecutive numbers of a given positive number.

So for example 124999012 would calculate 27.

I already wrote a function that calculates the sum of the digits of a number:

```
function sumDigits(n)
{
    var str = n.toString();
    var result = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        result = result + parseInt(str.charAt(i));
    }
    return result;
 }
```

Comment: so... what exactly is not working here?

Comment: @h2ooooooo changing to `i+=3` would jump some sequences, e.g. it would calculate `124` and `999` but not `249`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im a bit bored so I also did my own algorithm. Here is my solution:

```
function sumDigits(n) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, Array.prototype.map.call("" + n, function (s, ix) {
    return [+s, +n.toString()[ix + 1], +n.toString()[ix + 2]]
      .reduce(function (prev, curr) { return prev + (curr || 0) });
  }));
}
```

And of course, [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vevLo7d/2/).

**Step by step:**

1) Convert the array to an array of three elements, the current element and the next 2 elements:

```
Array.prototype.map.call(n.toString(), function (s, ix) {
  return [+s, +n.toString()[ix + 1], +n.toString()[ix + 2]];
});
```

2) Get the sum of that three elements for each item in the array:

```
item.reduce(function (prev, curr) { return prev + (curr || 0) });
```

`curr` will be undefined for the last elements of the array, so it may be converted to `0`.

3) Get the `max` for that last array:

```
Math.max.apply(null, array);
```

Thats it!

Answer (score 0):

You would want something like this which uses `Array.splice` and `Math.max`

```
function highestNum(n){
  var arr = [], nArr = (n+"").split("");
  while(nArr.length > 0)
     arr.push(nArr.splice(0,3).reduce(function(t, c){ return +t + +c }, 0));
  return Math.max.apply(null, arr);
}
```

What it is doing is, first it converts the number into string and then using `Array.splice`, you split the array into fragments of 3 elements and then you use `Array.reduce` to get the sum of those three numbers which you push in another array. And then you use `Math.max` and `Function.apply` to get the highest value which you return using the `return` operator.

Comment: Perhaps explain why/how this works. Separately, why keep an *array* of results?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah! String concat was happening. Corrected and explained it a bit

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumDigits(n)
{
    var str = n.toString();
    var result = 0;
    var temp=0;

    //for safety check length of the string
    // if it is not longer than 3 characters then just sum them up and return
    if (str.length<=3)
    {
      for(var i = 0; i < Math.Min(3,str.length); i++)
         result += parseInt(str.charAt(i));
    }
    else
    {
      //now look for biggest 3 consecutive numbers,
      //you wanna sum up 3 digits starting at index 0, and compare it with the max value you have calculated so far
      for(var i = 0; i < str.length-3; i++)
      {
          //calculate the sum of 3 consecutive numbers starting at index i
          temp = parseInt(str.charAt(i)) + parseInt(str.charAt(i+1)) + parseInt(str.charAt(i+2));
          //compare it to the current max, if it is greater than the current max, set it as the result
          if (temp>result)
              result = temp;
      }
    }
    return result;
 }
```

Comment: this is OP's code, corrected and readable. I would assume that it is useful for the OP.

Comment: Now that it has comments it may be.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function sumDigits(number)
{
    var numberString = "" + number;
    var max = -1;
    for(var i = 0; i < numberString.length - 3; i++)
    {
        var number1 = parseInt(numberString.charAt(i));
        var number2 = parseInt(numberString.charAt(i + 1));
        var number3 = parseInt(numberString.charAt(i + 2));
        var tempTotal = number1 + number2 + number3;
        if(tempTotal > max)
        {
            max = tempTotal;
        }
    }
    window.alert("" + max);
    return max;
}
```

You could start with the first three digits and loop through until you have tested every combination of 3 consecutive numbers.  Just add the 3 numbers together and if it is greater than the current max set the current max to the temp value.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a situation where a regular expression would work well. I'm not a RegExp expert and someone may point out a floor with doing it this way?

Javascript

```js
var num = 12224999011112,
    matches = num.toString().match(/(.)\1{2}/g),
    sum = 0;

if (matches) {
    sum = Math.max.apply(null, matches).toString().charAt() * 3;
}

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sum));
```

First, convert the number into a string so that you can use a RegExp. We then match all occurrences where we have 3 concurrent characters. If we have any matches then we choose the mathematically largest. We convert this to a string, take the first character and multiply it by 3.